# Hibernate.Initialize(x.getXX) with Spring and Junit

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit

I use to hibernate before and I require an opensession to use Hibernate.Initialize()

but apparently for Spring, if OpenSessionInViewInterceptor is set up properly, it can use Hibernate.Initialize() anywhere.

My question is, what must I setup to use Hibernate.Initialize() in JUnit?

Comment: You may be asking the wrong question, spring has very good support for testing your database code.  Why would you go to this level of complexity in your tests if you are using spring? What are you attempting to test?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` is precisely to leave the Hibernate session open until the view has been rendered. This is why you can call `Hibernate.initialize()` "anywhere": Spring doesn't close the session until the request has been completely handled by the view.

So the answer is always the same: to be able to call this method, the session must be opened.

Comment: Controllers should be tested by mocking the services. Services should be tested by mocking the DAOs and other service dependencies. You shouldn't deal with Hibernate in such unit tests. Hibernate should only be relevant when testing DAOs: you populate a test database, execute your queries using the DAO under test, and check that the query returns the correct values.

Comment: well what if I wish to unit test against database for accuracy. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Unit test what? PLease provide a concrete example.